# My new graphics card is not working

Tags: graphics-card, vga, dvi, amd-radeon

recently I've bought a new Radeon HD 6570 video card from ebay, I put it in my pc, and it has worked for a month. Then all of a sudden one day my monitor shut down and my fans went to full RPM, and I had to force shut my pc.

I used a different card, and the machine works fine. Every time when I put this new card in, the pc works for maybe 15 minutes to one hour and same thing happens. Drivers were up to date, my power suppy is good (450w) , my processor is intel celeron dual core e3200 2.4Gh, so the processor isn't taking too much power so that the gpu can't run.

Only problem was that I had to use the vga/dvi adapter, my monitor is vga and gpu has only 2 ports, dvi-i and that other dvi, I can't remember, but I've put the adapter on dvi-i because it wouldn't work on the other one. Could this cause trouble, and it there a way to see some error message or something on why my PC shuts down...

Comment: Does the machine have a good airflow? Sounds like it is overheating!

Comment: Well yes, and I've tried turning on the temp check as soon as I turn my pc on, and the temperature is about 39-40 degrees

Comment: I mean it's 39-40 right before the shutdown

Comment: In that case, can you remove the graphic card (do you have onboard VGA) to see if the same issue persists?

Comment: I have removed the card, put another one (128Mb ati radeon, I don't know it's exact name, but it's much older) and everything works

Comment: But with this older card I don't need a dvi/vga adapter

Comment: Well, I think you know the issue based upon your research, the card seems to be duff... Take it back, it will be under warranty

Comment: Well I've bought it online, and if I send it back, and then get a new one customs would cost me more than a repair probably :\ But no one can tell me the exact problem here, because I live ina  small town

Comment: Try the card in another PC, maybe a friend's PC.  Check if you get the same result.  If so the card is stuffed.

Comment: Yeah I have tried, same result

Comment: What does it mean when it's stuffed?

Comment: The card is defective.  Only option is to take it back and purchase a new one.

Comment: Do a test, get into the CCC and set things manually in the "AMD Overdrive" section.  not to overdrive it, to just stop the auto.

Comment: hmm, can I do it now, and then change the card, or I have to do it fast with a new card?

Comment: Is it that bad?  Get the fan going fast , it might give you more time. Is it still under warrenty?

Comment: Well yeah, it worked just fine before, and yes it is but I would have to sent it to UK because I bought it from ebay

Comment: If you had another card in of the same type , without tearing out the registry stuff for CCC, it is possible you may confuse some things in there for it.   When I changed up my card the old driver still worked, but i still cleaned it up and found this weeks most stable driver to install , which at the time was 13.4

Answer (score 0):

Contact customer support for your card. As it's within 3 months, the retailer should have responsibility depending what country you are in. If no, the manufacturer will be responsible. Either way, they may be able to provide you with a replacement card before you send yours off so you are not without a card. They may also be able to supply a shipping label and mark the package at 0 value to avoid customs and shipping charges.

Comment: He mentioned in comments that he bought from eBay. Support would most likely need original proof of purchase.

Comment: Oh I missed the ebay bit. Manufacturers can usually tell the original manufacture date from the serial number, so there's still hope. He should have got an email from the ebay seller containing an invoice for the product, or a paypal invoice when it was delivered within the box if it turned out the manufacturer was over a year ago.